# Why are time_of_day and hh_mm_ss two different types in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

The C++20 standard defines 2 types that store a time during the day: `chrono::hh_mm_ss` and `chrono::time_of_day`.
Both seem to store a duration since midnight, but because of DST-effects, callers should only use the hours, minutes, seconds and subseconds elements.
[www.cppreference.com](https://www.cppreference.com) gives exactly the same description for both types:

> The class template ... splits a std::chrono::duration representing
> time since midnight into a "broken down" time such as
> hours:minutes:seconds, with the precision of the split determined by
> the Duration template parameter. ... It is primarily a formatting
> tool.

The only difference seems to be that `chrono::time_of_day` mentions 12-hour/24-hour formatting and `chrono::hh_mm_ss` doesn't.

In [Howard Hinnant's GitHub library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) `time_of_day` is defined like this:

```
template <class Duration>
using time_of_day = hh_mm_ss<Duration>;
```

So why have 2 different types for this?

Comment: I've looked at the C++20 standard and I can't find `time_of_day` anywhere.

Comment: Just 'guessing' here, but would the `hh_mm_ss` type be usable for something like a counter, where the 'hours' field could well be >24? Presumably, the `time_of_day` type doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/ is great<del>, but not perfect</del>.  Ok, maybe it *is*.  Where else can you get this kind of speed for fixes?! (note the second comment below this answer). :-)

[Howard Hinnant's GitHub library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) originally had just `time_of_day`.  And that was part of the proposal for C++20.  During the standardization process, `time_of_day` was renamed to `hh_mm_ss`, and a few API adjustments were made.

Here is the paper that proposed these changes: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1466r3.html

[Howard Hinnant's GitHub library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) "implemented" this change, but left a `time_of_day` type alias just for backwards compatibility with existing users of this library.

In short, there is no `chrono::time_of_day`, there is only `chrono::hh_mm_ss`:  http://eel.is/c++draft/time.hms

---

Please note the very helpful comment below from Nicol Bolas.

Comment: Note that cppreference [doesn't list `time_of_day` as being part of `std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). The listing was changed back in February. But there is an unlinked page for `time_of_day`.

Comment: Those pages have been zapped.